# Окно ввода логина/пароля

Tags: c#, wpf

На моей форме в WPF есть кнопка **LogOut**, после нажатия на которую появляется диалоговое окно, где нужно ввести логин/пароль.

Если с первой попытки ввести верно, диалоговое окно закрывается - все верно.

А если ввести в первый раз неверные данные, то при второй, третьей и т.д. попытке все время выдает сообщение, что нужно ввести верные данные, тоесть как будто неверные данные были введены. Не пойму, что ни так

```
private async void buttonLogOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoginDialogData result = await this.ShowLoginAsync(
        "Authentication",
        "Enter your credentials", 
        new LoginDialogSettings { ColorScheme = this.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme });

    bool isUserDataCorrect = false;
    do
    {
        if (result.Username == "Dima" ||
            result.Password == "123456")
        {
            isUserDataCorrect = true;
        }
        else
        {
            await this.ShowLoginAsync(
                            "Wrong data, try again",
                            "Enter your credentials",
                            new LoginDialogSettings { ColorScheme = this.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme });
        }
    } while (isUserDataCorrect == false);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хотели, вероятно, `result.Username == "Dima" && result.Password == "123456"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы теряете вновь полученные данные. Надо так:

```
private async void buttonLogOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoginDialogData result = await this.ShowLoginAsync(
        "Authentication",
        "Enter your credentials", 
        new LoginDialogSettings { ColorScheme = this.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme });

    bool isUserDataCorrect = false;
    do
    {
        if (result.Username == "Dima" &&
            result.Password == "123456")
        {
            isUserDataCorrect = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = await this.ShowLoginAsync(
          /*^^^^^^^^^*/ "Wrong data, try again",
                        "Enter your credentials",
                        new LoginDialogSettings { ColorScheme = MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme });
        }
    } while (isUserDataCorrect == false);
}
```

Или проще:

```
private async void buttonLogOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var title = "Enter your credentials";
    var settings = new LoginDialogSettings
            {
                ColorScheme = MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme
            };
    while (true)
    {
        var result = await this.ShowLoginAsync("Authentication", title, settings);
        if (result.Username == "Dima" && result.Password == "123456")
            break;
        title = "Wrong data, try again";
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает

Comment: @dmitrykozyr: Пожалуйста!